# $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I must admit that I've forgotten how to do multivariable limits.  Nevertheless I need to know whether the following exists:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$$

Would it be as simple as defining a function $(x^2+y^2)\mapsto z$.  Then $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2} = \lim_{z\to 0^+} \frac{\sin(z)}{z} = 1?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Change to polar coordinates and use a well-known limit. One does not even need to go to polar coordinates, but that is a useful move in general when the denominator is $x^2+y^2$. (Your solution is correct.)

Comment: So $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2} = \lim_{r\to 0} \frac{\sin(r^2)}{r^2}$?

Comment: Yes, and that limit is $1$, as you know.

Comment: @user341126: You are welcome. You may have forgotten a bit about $2$ variable limits, but as you saw, this one is essentially a one variable problem, and you have not forgotten about those.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. You may use polar coodinates, $x=r \cos \theta$, $y=r \sin \theta$, then you initial function writes
$$
\frac{\sin (r^2)}{r^2}
$$ and consider $r \to 0$.